# How proc gets updated about the devices

Tags: linux, alsa, proc

If i do cat /proc/asound/cards it lists all the sound card details from where proc gets this information.This file is continuously updating what if i want to make a manual entry

Comment: Very similar question on SuperUser: [How does /proc/* work?](http://superuser.com/q/619955/53590). (Fair warning: the accepted, and by far highest-voted, answer is my own.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `/proc` (and `/sys`) are kernel interfaces.  Nothing in there is a real file on disk.  The information comes directly from the OS.  The individual files are kind of like socket interfaces, and when you read them you are making a request for data.

The [proc filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) apparently originates with UNIX 8 (although the Linux implementation, like most other implementations, was cloned from Plan 9 from Bell Labs) and is in keeping with the "everything is a file" UNIX adage.  It primarily represents individual running processes (the top level numbers are pids) but can, as you note, include some other stuff as well -- which overlaps on Linux with the more hardware oriented `/sys`.

As a note, occasionally I see people looking for "better alternatives" to getting the proc information programmatically, where "better alternatives" means system calls like `sysctl()` or `ioctl()`.  This seems to be rooted in the misconception that reading proc or sys files involves some I/O overhead like reading a regular file would.  It doesn't, and while some OS's (FreeBSD, I think) have done the opposite, on Linux `sysctl()` calls are depreciated:

From **man 2 sysctl**:

> use of this system call has long been discouraged, and it is so
>   unloved that it is likely to disappear in a future kernel version.
>   Remove it from your programs now; use the /proc/sys interface instead.

So there you have it: on linux at least, procfs is the officially recommended source for info from the kernel.  There are no "better alternatives".

Answer (score 1):

The files in `/proc` are not actually stored anywhere; when you try to read them, the kernel calls a function in the appropriate driver to get the file's contents.

In the case of `/proc/asound/cards`, this ends up at the function [snd_card_info_read](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/sound/core/init.c?id=7bb2491b35a254fe6fd592c32a142a2f2f31fe6e#n744), which generates its output from ALSA's internal sound card list.

You cannot add another entry without instantiating another sound card driver.

Comment: Is there any way to edit the conf and create one

Comment: @ganeshredcobra : Not via `proc`, no.  It is generally read-only -- it's for information, not configuration.

Comment: What if i want to create a custom device node like /dev/snd/custom_dev.Is there any method to create this other than using mknod.I want to create the dev file inside snd folder itself

Comment: What do want to do with this device node? I'd guess you should write your own sound driver.